# SSIS get only Year of a derived column that is a datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, derived-column

I need to make the `FORM_YEAR` the year of a derived column. The derived column is called `Invoice_Document_Date` and its data type is DateTime so I only want to grab the year. For my expression I wrote `YEAR(dc_Invoice_Document_Date)` but that doesn't seem to be right. What am I missing that will make this expression successful?

Comment: Why is the data type of the derived column datetime?

Comment: The column it is getting mapped to requires a datetime data type.

Comment: The target data type is a `datetime`. The result of a `year` operation will be an integer. So, you need to something to make the year number into a valid datetime data type. Typically, I see people peg this to a particular point in time - midnight on January 1 or 11:59:59.997 December 31 but your business requirements might be different. I have a client where the year starts April 1. So, what's the business need here? Once we know that, then it's a matter of building a string to represent the day and month along with the derived year

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the column SSIS data type is not `DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET` or `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`. Since in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/year-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) they mentioned that:

> The expression fails to validate when a date literal is explicitly cast to one of these date data types: DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET and DT_DBTIMESTAMP2.

You can try to convert the `dc_Invoice_Document_Date` to `DT_DATE` or `DT_DBDATE` or `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` data types. As example:

```
YEAR((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[dc_Invoice_Document_Date]))
```

You can also use [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datepart-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function as follows:

```
DATEPART("yy",[dc_Invoice_Document_Date]))
```